# remark boxes design

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, box

I found this box that I like for remarks and I want to put "remark"[image] instead of!
Here is the .tex code with the pdf

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{marker}[1][]{enhanced,
    before skip=2mm,after skip=3mm,
    boxrule=0.4pt,left=5mm,right=2mm,top=1mm,bottom=1mm,
    colback=yellow!50,
    colframe=yellow!20!black,
    sharp corners,rounded corners=southeast,arc is angular,arc=3mm,
    underlay={%
        \path[fill=tcbcolback!80!black] ([yshift=3mm]interior.south east)--++(-0.4,-0.1)--++(0.1,-0.2);
        \path[draw=tcbcolframe,shorten <=-0.05mm,shorten >=-0.05mm] ([yshift=3mm]interior.south east)--++(-0.4,-0.1)--++(0.1,-0.2);
        \path[fill=yellow!50!black,draw=none] (interior.south west) rectangle node[white,rotate=0]{\Huge\bfseries ! } ([xshift=4mm]interior.north west);
    },
    drop fuzzy shadow,#1}

\begin{document}
    \begin{marker}
        Foo
    \end{marker}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

See comments in the code where changes were made.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{marker}[1][]{enhanced,
    before skip=2mm,after skip=3mm,
    boxrule=0.4pt,
    left=15mm, % changed from left=5mm
    right=2mm,top=1mm,bottom=1mm,
    colback=yellow!50,
    colframe=yellow!20!black,
    sharp corners,rounded corners=southeast,arc is angular,arc=3mm,
    underlay={%
        \path[fill=tcbcolback!80!black] ([yshift=3mm]interior.south east)--++(-0.4,-0.1)--++(0.1,-0.2);
        \path[draw=tcbcolframe,shorten <=-0.05mm,shorten >=-0.05mm] ([yshift=3mm]interior.south east)--++(-0.4,-0.1)--++(0.1,-0.2);
        \path[fill=yellow!50!black,draw=none] (interior.south west) rectangle 
            node[white,rotate=0]{Remark} % changed node text from ! to Remark
            ([xshift=14mm]interior.north west); % changed xshift-value from 4mm to 14mm
    },
    drop fuzzy shadow,#1}

\begin{document}
    \begin{marker}
        Foo
    \end{marker}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much